# Converting a list of Eithers to an Either containing a list

Tags: haskell

I have a function which returns a list of `Either` items. If it only contains `Right` items I want to return a single `Right` containing a list of the values in the original `Right` items, but if it contains any `Left` items I want a single `Left` containing a list of the values in the original `Left` items. So if I have:
`[Right "a", Right "b", Right "c"]`
it should become:
`Right ["a", "b", "c"]`
but if I have:
`[Right "a", Left "b", Right "c", Left "d"]`
it should become:
`Left ["b", "d"]`

Note: The `sequence` function from Control.Monad isn't suitable because it only keeps the first `Left` item.

I have come up with this:

```
eitherList :: [Either a1 a2] -> Either [a1] [a2]
eitherList l = if null lefts
               then Right rights
               else Left lefts
  where f1 (Left a) (al, ar) = (a : al, ar)
        f1 (Right a) (al, ar) = (al, a : ar)
        (lefts, rights) = foldr f1 ([], []) l
```

but it seems clumsy. Is there a simpler or better way of doing this? I'm just starting to learn about functors and monads and I'm wondering if these are relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the heavy lifting can be done by `Data.Either.partitionEithers`:

```
eitherList :: [Either a1 a2] -> Either [a1] [a2]
eitherList l = case (partitionEithers l) of
                  ([], rs) -> Right rs
                  (ls, _) -> Left ls
```

(The implementation of `partitionEithers` is very similar to what you wrote for the fold.)

Answer (score 5):

> The `sequence` function from `Control.Monad` isn't suitable because it only keeps the first `Left` item.

You had the right idea, just missing a few details. There is a package, [`validation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation), that offers a type called [`Validation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-1.1.2/docs/Data-Validation.html#t:Validation), which is shaped just like `Either`:

```
data Validation err a
  = Failure err
  | Success a
```

But notably, its `Applicative` instance works as you want, appending the “error” values together:

```
instance (Semigroup err) => Applicative (Validation err) where

  pure = Success

  Failure e1 <*> Failure e2 = Failure (e1 <> e2)
  Failure e1 <*> Success _  = Failure e1
  Success _  <*> Failure e2 = Failure e2
  Success f  <*> Success a  = Success (f a)
```

Unlike `Either`, `Validation` can’t have a `Monad` instance, so you need to use the more general `sequenceA` (or `traverse`) instead of `sequence` (or `mapM`):

```
sequence  :: (Traversable t, Monad m)       => t (m a) -> m (t a)
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)

mapM      :: (Traversable t, Monad m)       => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
traverse  :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

The `Data.Validation` module exports various functions for converting to and from `Either`. For your purpose, a good choice is `liftError`:

```
liftError :: (b -> e) -> Either b a -> Validation e a

singleton :: a -> [a]
singleton = pure

liftError singleton :: Either e a -> Validation [e] a
```

Here it is all together:

```
import qualified Data.Validation as Validation

eitherList :: [Either e a] -> Either [e] [a]
eitherList = Validation.toEither . traverse (Validation.liftError pure)
-- Note: ‘traverse f’ = ‘sequenceA . fmap f’
```

And your examples work as expected:

```
> example1 = [Right "a", Right "b", Right "c"]

> example2 = [Right "a", Left "b", Right "c", Left "d"]

> eitherList example1
Right ["a","b","c"]

> eitherList example2
Left ["b","d"]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I've accepted Chepner's answer because it's simple and doesn't need any extra packages installed, but this will help me in trying to understand how monads etc. can be used.